# Reading and writing to a config file

Tags: php, file

I want to code a few PHP pages, which reads and write some settings from a config.php file. The structure of config.php file

```
config["exp-date"] = '10-09-2011'; 
config["np"] = 3;
```

I can just include the file and read the settings, but is there any easy way to change settings via a form. I know of fopen and other, but still not getting what to do after opening.

Update: How can I read the whole array at once?

Comment: Have you tried doing any writing? If so, what happened that wasn't what you were after?

Comment: I opened but cannot decide how to go ahead with writing. Sometimes I might just want to change the date. 

I thought I can read the whole file, change appropriate settings and then write it back but thought there might be a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have the $config var set inside your config.php (btw be careful with the var name, it's very common and you don't want it to be overwrited).

```
$config = array();
$config['todo'] = 'pony';
```

All you have to do is to modify the $config array with your form (this part is up to you), and then, write the new $config array in the config.php file like this:

```
file_put_contents("config.php", var_export($config, true));
```

And that's it! :)

Comment: Doing that won't affect other members of array? Since we are creating a whole new array and then exporting it, other settings wont change?

Comment: Be sure to only edit the keys you need on the $config array. If you unset the "todo" key, you lost if forever - you must edit the whole $config array.

Comment: not if you load the old settings in the same array and merge it with the altered settings ;) eg; `$settings = array_merge($settings, array('todo' => 'pony'); `

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use an INI File? PHP has a function to parse an INI File.. I Think Its `parse_ini_file();`

Comment: I thought about it, but found that a lot of php programs store settings in a php file.